# How to add css background styles using vanilla-lazyload

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I'm looking at using vanilla lazyload to improve the performance of the website. However, I am struggling to find a way to lazyload background images with styles.

The background images I have on the website have the following syntax:

```
<section class="ptb-100 gradient-overly-bottom" style="background: url('assets/img/hero-2.jpg')no-repeat center center / cover fixed">
```

Using vanilla lazyload, the syntax changed to the following:

```
<section class="ptb-100 gradient-overly-bottom lazy" data-bg="assets/img/hero-2.jpg">
```

Output from vanilla lazyload:

```
<section class="ptb-100 gradient-overly-bottom lazy entered loaded" data-bg="assets/img/hero-2.jpg" data-ll-status="loaded" style="background-image: URL("assets/img/hero-2.jpg");">
```

As you can observe, the output doesn't include a background URL attribute, it replaces with a background image.

Is there a way to add styles after the background image URL?

Comment: wouldn't it be enough to just add your missing styles with a stylesheet? Or inline if you have to, haven't used vanilla lazyload but I would assume they are only changing the background-image attribute and don't remove others.

Comment: Why didn't I try that ‍♂️ thank you it works

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always madify the CSS rules for the lazy class. Here's an example:

```
.lazy {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

and this is for the html

```
<section class="ptb-100 gradient-overly-bottom lazy" data-bg="assets/img/hero-2.jpg">
  <!-- content of the section -->
</section>
```